# Module not found Error: error in pm4py evaluation module

Tags: google-colaboratory

I have pm4py installed on colab but I keep receiving this error that pm4py.evaluation doesn't exist.

Comment: Please include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. It may be helpful to read about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should also read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).